# How to initiate an instance of pyttsx from within a class?

Tags: python-2.7, class, initialization, text-to-speech, pyttsx

I would like to make an instance from pyttsx inside a class and have a settings function to change the speech rate. But the **init** is not working properly as it gives the following error message:

```
AttributeError: TTSengine instance has no attribute 'say'
```

From my codes:

```
import pyttsx

class TTSengine():
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = pyttsx.init()
    def settings(self):
        self.rate = self.engine.getProperty('rate')
        self.engine.setProperty('rate', self.rate-50)

y = pyttsx.init()
print y
y.say('I am ok')
y.runAndWait()

x = TTSengine()
print x
x.say('I am ok')
x.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class itself doesn't have a say function. Your class has a pyttsx engine as a member variable, so the following should work:

```
x = TTSengine()
x.engine.say('I am ok')
x.engine.runAndWait()
```